# C RPC without the stubs

Tags: c, rpc

I have this program that I want other processes to be able to call functions on (through unix sockets). The message protocol is very simple, the function name, a function signature, and a buffer (char *) that holds the parameters.

When a module in my program wants to allow a function to be accessible, it registers the name and signature with the library. The problem I'm facing is with physically calling the function once the request comes in. I have looked at RPC and java RMI-like libraries, but those require that I generate stubs to wrap calls. The system I am working on is very dynamic and I also have to interface with other peoples code that I can't modify.

So basically, a function might look like:

```
int somefunc(int someparam, double another)
{
    return 1234;
}
```

now I register with the library:

```
//           func ptr   name       signature
REG_FUNCTION(somefunc, "somefunc", "i:id");
```

When the request comes in, I do some error checking, once valid I want to call the function. So I have the variables:

```
void * funcptr = (the requested function);
char * sig = (the function signature);
char * params = (a buffer of function parameters);
//note that the params buffer can hold data types of arbitrary lengths
```

How can I call the function with the parameters in C?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you need the signature for? Does the client call the function or do they pass requests to the library containing somefunc? Some clarification will be of help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is completely solvable in general, using only C. You don't know the calling convention used by the target function, for instance. There is a risk that you end up "cheating" the compiler, or at least having to second-guess it. What if the compiler decided to build the registered function using arguments passed in registers, perhaps due to some optimization setting (or what if it was built with a different compiler?).

There's also no way in general to express in C that you want to call a function with a given set of arguments, and that the values for the arguments need to be unpacked from a buffer of random bytes.

You could do something horrible like this:

```
enum { VOID_INT, VOID_INT_DOUBLE, VOID_DOUBLE_INT, ... } Signature;

void do_call(const void *userfunction, const void *args, Signature sig)
{
  switch(signature)
  {
    case VOID_INT:
    {
      int x = *(int *) args;
      void (*f)(int) = userfunction;
      f(x);
      break;
    }
    case VOID_INT_DOUBLE:
    ...
  }
}
```

But it's quite clear that this doesn't live on the same continent as scalability. You could of course auto-generate this code, for some reasonable set of return types and argument types. You'd still be a bit out in the cold for casting function pointers to/from `void *`, but that might be acceptable. You'd still always run the risk of someone handing you a signature that you don't have pre-generated code for, though.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [libffi](http://sourceware.org/libffi/). This library allows to call function with a set of parameters specified at runtime.